# How to Get TFS WorkItem URL depending on WorkItem ID

Tags: c#, tfs

i could successfully add bugs into TFS programmatically,

```
var tfsURI = new Uri("http://test:8080/tfs");
var networkCredential1 = new NetworkCredential("test", "test!");

ICredentials credential = (ICredentials)networkCredential1;
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential winCred = new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential(credential);
VssCredentials vssCredentials = new VssCredentials(winCred);

using (TfsTeamProjectCollection collection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfsURI, vssCredentials))
{
    collection.EnsureAuthenticated();
    WorkItemStore workItemStore = collection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
    Project teamProject = workItemStore.Projects["Test"];
    WorkItemType workItemType = teamProject.WorkItemTypes["Bug"];

    WorkItem Defect = new WorkItem(workItemType);
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"C:\\Document.docx");
    Attachment tfsAttachment = new Attachment(fi.FullName);
    Defect.Attachments.Add(tfsAttachment);

    Defect.Title = "Testing from VS to TFS Bug";
    Defect.Description = "Testing from VS to entered Bug in to TFS.";
    Defect.Fields["Assigned To"].Value = "Test";

    Defect.Save();
}
```

I have Newly Created WorkItem ID. Defect.ID provides me workitemID.

**How can i get the URL of newly created WOrkItem by passing ID.**
Let Me know if any API available? i need HTML Link of Newly created WorkItem so that anyone when click on URL, created WorkItem will be Open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution after lots of research, may help to someone in future:

```
var tfsURI = new Uri("http://test:8080/tfs");
var networkCredential1 = new NetworkCredential("test", "test!");

    ICredentials credential = (ICredentials)networkCredential1;
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential winCred = new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential(credential);
    VssCredentials vssCredentials = new VssCredentials(winCred);

    using (TfsTeamProjectCollection collection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfsURI, vssCredentials))
    {
        collection.EnsureAuthenticated();
        TswaClientHyperlinkService hyperlinkService = 
           collection.GetService<TswaClientHyperlinkService>();
        String TFSurl = hyperlinkService.GetWorkItemEditorUrl(17648).ToString(); //17648 WorkItem ID
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to directly return a single work item

`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=5.1`

However this will only get a url to the json data for the bug created, not the URL of the HTML page of the bug. Such as below output that I got

```
https://tfsurl:8080/_apis/wit/workItems/workitemID
```

When I load the above link in browser, I got JSON data, instead of the HTML page for the work item I created.

Guess you want to fetch the url of HTML in web portal.

https://tfsurl:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/PatrickProject/_workitems/edit/172/

In my case it was this and here DefaultCollection is the collection name and the PatrickProject is the project name. I used this url and got rid of the id '172' in this case and use the ID of newly created work item. This would return the URL to go to the work item HTML page.

So it's a fixed format, if you have Newly Created WorkItem ID and collection name , project name, you just need to follow above format and change the last value of work item ID. That's it , ignore of which work item type you created.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: i need html Link so that once TFS workitem created Link for perticular workitem gets updated in one of out table in Database.....so that any one who will click on Link can Open TFS WorkItem directly to Check